# Falha 404 com ASP.NET MVC quando arquivo anexado é grande

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, upload, file-upload

Estou utilizando o plugin [jquery.filer](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer) para enviar arquivos anexar arquivos no meu formuláro.

Escolhi esse por ter sido um plugin que consegui manipulá-lo para enviar os dados dos outros inputs juntamente com os arquivos e evitar pastas temporárias.

**Funciona bem com arquivos "pequenos"**, mas dá falha ao enviar arquivos ligeiramente "grandes", exemplo, um de **250MB**.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Não sei se pode ser o tipo do arquivo, no momento, estou testando com um GDB (arquivo de banco de dados do ***Firebird***).

Claro que coloquei um ***breakpoint*** logo na primeira linha para verificar se era algum tipo de erro no método (a action) que recebe o POST, mas não chegou nele, ou seja, a action não chegou a ser executada.

[image: Tela de envio]

Configuração do plugin:

```js
$atendimentoForm.find("#Arquivos").filer({
    limit: null,
    maxSize: "102400",
    extensions: null,
    changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><div class="jFiler-input-inner"><div class="jFiler-input-icon"><i class="icon-jfi-cloud-up-o"></i></div><div class="jFiler-input-text"><h3>Arraste e o solte os arquivos aqui para enviá-los</h3> <span style="display:inline-block; margin: 15px 0">ou</span></div><a class="jFiler-input-choose-btn blue">Clique aqui para selecioná-los</a></div></div>',
    showThumbs: true,
    appendTo: null,
    theme: "dragdropbox",
    templates: {
        box: '<ul class="jFiler-item-list"></ul>',
        item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                    <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                            </div>\
                            {{fi-image}}\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                            <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                <li>{{fi-progressBar}}</li>\
                            </ul>\
                            <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                            </ul>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </li>',
        itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                    <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                            </div>\
                            {{fi-image}}\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                            <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}} {{fi-size2}}</span>\
                            </ul>\
                            <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                            </ul>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </li>',
        itemAppendToEnd: false,
        removeConfirmation: false,
        _selectors: {
            list: '.jFiler-item-list',
            item: '.jFiler-item',
            progressBar: '.bar',
            remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action',
        }
    },
    addMore: true,
    clipBoardPaste: true,
    excludeName: null,
    beforeShow: function () { return true },
    onSelect: function () { },
    afterShow: function () { },
    onRemove: function () { },
    onEmpty: function () { },
    captions: {
        button: "Escolher os Arquivos",
        feedback: "Escolha os arquivos que deseja enviar",
        feedback2: "Arquivos selecionados",
        drop: "Arraste os arquivos aqui para enviar",
        removeConfirmation: "Você tem certeza que deseja remover esse arquivo?",
        errors: {
            filesLimit: "Somente {{fi-limit}} arquivos podem ser enviados.",
            filesType: "Tipo de arquivo não permitido.",
            filesSize: "{{fi-name}} é muito grande! Por favor, escolha arquivos com menos de {{fi-maxSize}} GB.",
            filesSizeAll: "Todos os arquivos juntos são muito grandes! Por favor, escolha um total de até {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
        }
    }
});
```

Configuração de envio:

```js
$atendimentoForm.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $progress = $atendimentoForm.find(".progress .progress-bar");
    $progress.closest(".form-group").css("display", "block");
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                    $progress.width(percentComplete + "%").text(percentComplete + "%");
                    if (percentComplete === 100) { $progress.width("100%").text("100%"); }
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        url: "/Atendimentos/Create",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $progress.closest(".form-group").hide();
            if (response.result) {
                showMessage("Atenção", "Atendimento inserido com sucesso!", "success", function (option) {
                    location.href = "/Atendimentos/Edit/" + response.atendimentoId;
                });
            } else if (response.errors) {
                showMessage("Atenção", "Não foi possível incluir o Atendimento!\n\n" + response.errors, "error");
            } else {
                showMessage("Atenção", "Não foi possível incluir o Atendimento!", "error");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Com esse carinha: `data: new FormData(this),` eu envio `Descricao, Data, Usuários` e todos os outros campos do formulário juntamente em um `request` apenas.

**Alguém sabe dizer se é do plugin ou do ASP.NET [MVC]?**

**Qual outro que não dá esse tipo de problema e permite upload de arquivos simultâneos e envio dos dados do formulário juntamente com os `input[type=file]`?**

---

### EDIT

Esse foi um detalhe que esqueci de incluir:

```xml
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" 
    enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" 
    responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="4096000" 
   requestLengthDiskThreshold="4096000"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: resolvido com requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength, em system.webServer e security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um limite de tamanho para fazer upload de arquivos no ASP.NET.
Mas existe a possibilidade de configurar e aumentar o limite.

Tente configurar o **maxRequestLength** no seu WebConfig e realize um teste.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Onde xxx é o valor em kB. O default é 4096 (ou seja, 4 MB).
No seu exemplo, 250MB * 1000kB = 250000 kB.

Comment: Na verdade eu havia esquecido de incluir esse detalhe: `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="2147483647" 
   requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647"/>` que já está em meu Web.config.

Comment: E a resposta de erro seria mesmo 404 NotFound?

Comment: O limite para maxRequestLength é para o tamanho de cada arquivo em uma solicitação ou a somatória de todos eles? Considerando a configuração default eu poderia enviar 1000 arquivos de 3,5 MB?