# Limite para envio de arquivos

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, file-upload

Tenho um projeto em Asp Net MVC .NET Framework 4 da seguinte forma:

View:

```
<div class="file-content">
    <label class="custom-file-upload">
          <input type="file" id="importar-arquivos" multiple accept=".pdf" name="arquivo" required />
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-n file-icon"></span> Escolher Arquivos
    </label>
    <br />
    <span id="file-selected">​​</span>
</div>

<div class="options-content">
    <img src="../Images/save-send.png" id="file-enviar" class="icon-action" title="Enviar" />
    <img src="../Images/btnerror.png" id="file-cancelar" class="icon-action" title="Cancelar" />
</div>

<script>
    (function () {
        $("#file-enviar").on("click", function () {
            try {
               var fileImput = $("#importar-arquivos");
                var arquivos = fileImput.get(0).files;

                if (arquivos.length > 0) {

                    prepararPDF(arquivos);

                } else {
                    alert("Selecione os arquivos para enviar!");
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                console.error("Erro ao enviar arquivo!", ex);
            }
        });

        function prepararPDF(arquivos) {
            var paramsData = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++) {
                paramsData.append("files", arquivos[i]);
            }

            enviarPDF(paramsData);
        }

        function enviarPDF(paramsData) {
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    IniciaLoad();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    FinalizaLoad();
                },
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "minhaURL",
                data: paramsData,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.debug("data", data);
                },
                fail: function () {
                    alert("Falhou!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Erro de Conexão");
                }
            });
        }

    })();
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MinhaAction(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
   return Json(files.Length, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ao realizar testes com poucos arquivos pequenos **não** obtive problema nenhum, mas ao tentar enviar múltiplos arquivos maiores então obtive o seguinte erro:

> **HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found** 
>   O módulo de filtragem de solicitação está configurado para negar uma solicitação que exceda o tamanho de conteúdo solicitado.

1. O problema é a **quantidade de arquivos**, o **tamanho de cada um
   deles** ou **a soma do tamanho de todos os arquivos**?
2. Qual o limite padrão para **quantidade** de arquivos e **tamanho** deles?
3. Como posso configurar um limite maior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Existem duas configurações a serem modificadas](http://forums.iis.net/t/1169846.aspx).

`maxRequestLength` indica o tamanho máximo de um upload suportado pelo ASP.NET
`maxAllowedContentLength` especifica o tamanho máximo do conteúdo de um request  suportado pelo IIS.

Amplie o tamanho aceitável de arquivos ajustando a seguinte entrada no arquivo **web.config**:

> web.config

```
 <system.web> 
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="104857600"/> 
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Onde `maxAllowedContentLength` é medido em bytes, [cujo valor default é 30000000](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits), (aproximadamente 28.6MB).

O número máximo de arquivos sequenciais a serem enviados é [4.294.967.295 (NTFS)](https://serverfault.com/a/18697/229892) ou pela soma de seus tamanhos mais o [cabeçalho multipart](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), o que for menor.

Caso o problema persista, ele pode pode estar no fato de que as configurações feitas no arquivo `web.config` podem ser substituídas por definições presentes tanto em `applicationhost.config` quanto em `machine.config`.

Se você tiver acesso a estes, verificar se a propriedade `overrideModeDefault` das seções correspondentes estão definidas como **Allow**, como no exemplo a seguir:

> machine.config

```
<requestFiltering overrideModeDefault="Allow">
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"/>        
</requestFiltering>
```

Não há, até onde sei, nenhuma maneira de substituir essas configurações se você não tiver acesso ao arquivo de configuração correspondente.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512698/1845714).

Comment: Muito obrigado por compartilhar sua sabedoria @OnoSendai , mas quero adquirir ainda mais! Qual seria o limite padrão para o tamanho dos arquivos? Qual o limite de arquivos (quantidade) posso enviar em uma única solicitação?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Respostas adicionadas à resposta. =)

Comment: pelo que entendi os 4.294.967.295 arquivos seriam o limite para um diretório NTFS, esse limite também vale para um envio POST como estou fazendo? Acredito que a quantidade de arquivos esteja mais relacionado com o `maxAllowedContentLength` como vc bem citou... Estou certo?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues correto. A limitação da quantidade de arquivos é relevante apenas para o NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

No `httpRuntime` dentro de seu `web.config` você pode especificar o `maxRequestLength` que vai determinar qual o tamanho máximo de suas requisições.

> O tamanho máximo de solicitações, em quilobytes.O tamanho padrão é
>   4096 KB (4 MB).

[Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

Existem outras perguntas e respostas referentes ao assunto.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94181/5846

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114102/5846

Comment: 4 MB por arquivo ou a somatória de todos não pode passar disso?
Ou seja, posso enviar 2 arquivos de 3 MB de boas?

Comment: Não sei ao certo, mas acredito que seja a soma dos arquivos

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! O @ElifazioBernadesDaSilva diz que o limite é para cada arquivo...
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155906/23192

Comment: Na verdade você está certo! Acabei de testar aqui e pude comprovar que o limite é a soma do tamanho de todos os arquivos na mesma requisição.

Comment: Mas é preciso configurar também o `maxAllowedContentLength` como citado pelo @OnoSendai

Answer (score 0):

O limite padrão para o tamanho de cada arquivo é 4mb ou 4096 KB no asp.net

Para configurar o tamanho para a aplicação inteira, basta acrescentar no seu web.config o seguinte:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

O valor xxx você substitui pelo valor máximo que quer permitir em kb.

Comment: Você disse: 
"Para configurar o tamanho para a aplicação inteira [...]". Mas é possível configurar um tamanho maior apenas para um contexto específico?

Comment: Se o limite padrão é para cada arquivo, então em teoria posso enviar 100 arquivos de 3,5 MB?

Comment: Fiz alguns testes aqui e pude ver que o limite não é para cada arquivo, mas sim para a soma do tamanho de todos os arquivos enviados na mesma requisição.