# Erro 500 ao tentar fazer Upload de Video com XMLHttpRequest ASp.net/C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

Tenho uma aplicação que faz upload de video utilizando `XMLHttpRequest` quando subi um video pequeno (`386Kb`) o video sobe normal, mas quando tento um video maior (`20Mb`) ele não atinge a função C# e o retorna erro 500.

Essa é minha função Front End :

```
document.getElementById('formItem').onsubmit = function (e) {

    var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object

    //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);

    xhr.open('POST', '/Unidade/Item/Cadastrar');

    if (xhr.upload) {
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded);
                var value = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                progressBar.style.width = value + "%";
                progressBar.innerText = value + "%";
            }
        }
        xhr.upload.onloadstart = function (e) {
            progressBar.value = 0;
            display.innerText = '0%';
        }
        xhr.upload.onloadend = function (e) {
            var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            $('#progressBar').css({ 'width': percentComplete + '%' });
            loadBtn.innerHTML = 'Iniciando o Upload';
        }
    }
    xhr.send(formdata);
    return false;
}
```

o erro retorna quando chamo `xhr.send(formdata);`, o vídeo menor atinge o método normalmente mas o maior da erro, os dois tem a mesma extensão (`.mp4`).
Caso faltar alguma informação me avisem.

input video :

```
 <video  controls poster="/Content/imagens/principais/Video-PlayButton.png" >' +
        <source src="' + e.target.result + '" type="video/mp4">

  </video>
```

Comment: Como está a "função" no servidor? Está utilizando o que no servidor? Asp Clássico, WebForms, Asp.NET MVC...

Comment: ASP.net Mvc, a partir do momento que o codigo atinge a função ASp.Net Mvc,  ele salva corretamente, se for preciso posto ela aqui.

Comment: Poste seu arquivo `Web.config`

Comment: Que parte você precisa do web.config??

Comment: Ah eu procurei e achei essa tag <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />  acabei de adicionar ao Web.config , vou testar.

Comment: Essa seria minha sugestão :p. Qualquer dúvida, existe [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155902/20615) que explica melhor o seu uso

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado, essa pergunta me ajudou muito ...